# Use of Javascript "this" keyword in functions

Tags: javascript, function, reference, this

I understand that Javascript isn't a true OO language and the introduction of ECMAScript 6 should alleviate some of these problems, but the use of the `this` keyword in Javascript is genuinely confusing me, at least when trying to replicate "private" functions in Javascript.

Consider the following code:

```
function Person() {

    this.name = "Blake";

    var sayHi = function() {
        console.log("Salutations. My name is " + this.name);

        this.name = "Jon";
        console.log("Salutations. My name is " + this.name);

        this.sayBye();
    };

    this.callSayHi = function() {
        console.log("O hai, my name is " + this.name);
        sayHi();
    };

    this.sayBye = function() {
        console.log("Goodbye " + this.name);
    };

};

var blake = new Person();
blake.callSayHi();
```

In the case of the `callSayHi()` function, the context is the object that invoked `callSayHi()`, or `blake`. So, the definition of `this` is the instance of `Person` called `blake` and the console outputs the following:

```
O hai, my name is Blake
```

Next, the `sayHi()` function gets called. At this point, I would assume that `this` would refer to `blake` again but the console says otherwise with some unexpected behavior:

```
Salutations. My name is result
```

Next, I try setting the mystery `this` reference and log to the console again:

```
Salutations. My name is Jon
```

At this point, however, I still don't know what `this` refers to, just that I've assigned a property on it and that that property had an old value of `result`.

Finally, to check if `this` does refer to `blake`, I call `sayBye()`, which gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So I know that `this` does not refer to `blake` in the context of `sayHi()`; what does `this` refer to, then? Does it refer to `sayHi` (narrower scope) or does it refer to the `window` (broader scope)?

Is there any way for me to declare a function who's context is `Person` that does not get explicitly assigned to a property (similar to a "private" function in languages like Java)?

*Finally, a much more general question*: if `this` refers to the `window` in my first question, how does the definition of `this.name` not bind to `sayHi`, and instead, binds to `window`? I made a function called `Person` and `this` refers to `Person` in that context, but when I make a function `sayHi`, `this` refers to `window`...? Is it because `sayHi` was defined as:

```
var sayHi = function() { ... }
```

...and not:

```
function sayHi() { ... }
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: JavaScript is a OO Programming language. It just doesn't implement the class pattern as you said. But you have the possibility to implement a class like structure. Also every variable is an object in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this:

```
function Person() {
  this.name = "Blake";

  return this;
};
Person.prototype.sayHi = function() {
  console.log("Salutations. My name is " + this.name);

  this.name = "Jon";
  console.log("Salutations. My name is " + this.name);

  this.sayBye();
};

Person.prototype.callSayHi = function() {
  console.log("O hai, my name is " + this.name);
  this.sayHi();
};

Person.prototype.sayBye = function() {
  console.log("Goodbye " + this.name);
};

var blake = new Person();
blake.callSayHi();
```

So here is some explanation:

Each function has their own variable scope which this is referring to If you define a function in a function, the new function is only available in the function, so their context is from the function. If you define a function on a prototype the context of the function is this.

Hope that helps